# Updating old Sharepoint site with Sharepoint 2010 - how to update old navigation

Tags: sharepoint

First off, I am not a programmer and so I am simply trying to update an old Sharepoint site using Sharepoint tools.  The difficulty I have been having is that the site has a lot of archives and pages that I don't want to recreate if possible.  Therefore, I have been renaming and adding pages to an old site (originally creating via an earlier version of Sharepoint) and as I create these new pages/site within the share they look and navigate very differently from the old.  How can I either update the old navigation to the new or vise versa so that the site all looks and navigates the same?

Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your old pages were probably edited using SharePoint Designer and that's why they do not get the new look&feel. You could reset this changes using Site Setting Reset to Site Definition option, but it could make changes to the site you don't want (it was probably edited for a reason). I would suggest making the change on a test copy and then you will see what is changed and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will allow programmers and non-programmers to work on navigation. You will be able to update the navigation using the site settings>navigation and allow the programmers to customize the styling however they wish. You can also put as many levels of sub-entres as you want.

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/